# PySpark - Cosine Similarity for text columns

Tags: python, pyspark

I am trying to perform cosine similarity analysis on text from two dataframes.

I have cleaned the text by removing all stop words and I have performed stemming.

I am left with two columns in my dataframes that look like this:
dataframe one only has one row for the stemmed column

```
df1 =

Stemmed col
every solut catch except new
```

while dataframe two has multiple rows for the stemmed column

```
df2= 

colum_num    stemmed col

    1         every except new
    2         didnt find solut ye
    3         fatal except main 
    4        access databas everi
```

I wish to get an output that displays each cosine similarity value next to the stemmed col and then I want to select the column with the highest cosine similarity

```
df_cosine_similarity = 

colum_num    stemmed col                cosine_similarity

    1         every except new               0.230
    2         didnt find solut ye            0.652
    3         fatal except main              0.095
    4        access databas everi            0.159


   original_text_body                highest_similarity        cosine_similarity
every solut catch except new           didnt find solut ye            0.652
```

so far, I know that I need to vectorized the stemmed text so I attempted to created a text to vector function:

```
def text_to_vector(text):
    words = WORD.findall(text)
    return Counter(words)

def get_cosine(vec1, vec2):
    intersection = set(vec1.keys()) & set(vec2.keys())
    numerator = sum([vec1[x] * vec2[x] for x in intersection])

    sum1 = sum([vec1[x] ** 2 for x in list(vec1.keys())])
    sum2 = sum([vec2[x] ** 2 for x in list(vec2.keys())])
    denominator = math.sqrt(sum1) * math.sqrt(sum2)

    if not denominator:
        return 0.0
    else:
        return float(numerator) / denominator
```

Unfortunately, these function are not  working the way they are supposed to

Comment: I did something similar recently, and would recommend using the TextVectorizer from SKLearn instead of a Counter. It's designed specifically for this type of application. SKLearn also has a built-in cosine similarity method which eliminates the need to write the math yourself.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to utilize spark and its functionality for this task

Comment: You should still be able to take advantage of those packages in a PySpark script. I was using PySpark as well in my scenario.